# Query to find the count of active days (days with status = ON) between specified dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, gaps-and-islands

I have a table as you can see below :

```
create table z_test_duration
( Days     date,
  Status   char(8)
);
```

Sample data is as below :

| Days | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | on |
| 1/2/2022 | on |
| 1/3/2022 | on |
| 1/4/2022 | off |
| 1/5/2022 | on |
| 1/6/2022 | off |
| 1/7/2022 | on |
| 1/8/2022 | on |
| 1/9/2022 | off |

The desired result is this

| ON_DATE | OFF_DATE | COUNT_OF_ACTIVE_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 1/4/2022 | 3 |
| 1/5/2022 | 1/6/2022 | 1 |
| 1/7/2022 | 1/9/2022 | 2 |

My solution so far is this :

```
select min(days) on_date, 
       off_day off_date, 
       off_day - min(days) cnt
       
  from (select t1.off_day, 
               t1.prev_offday, 
               t2.days            
          from (                
                select t.days off_day,
                        nvl(lag(t.days, 1) over(order by t.days),convert(datetime, '1/1/2022') - 100) prev_offday
                  from z_test_duration t
                 where t.status = 'off'
                                 
                ) t1
         inner join z_test_duration t2
            on t2.days > t1.prev_offday
           and t2.days < t1.off_day)
 group by off_day;
```

I'm thinking if there are better ways of solving this , It would be appreciated if you share your way of solving this .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no "nvl" function in SQL Server's Tsql dialect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an 'islands' problem.

One popular and efficient solution is to number rows in the desired order. When there is a gap in the sequence, the *difference* between the ordering column and the row number also jumps.

Let's look at that step by step. First, the numbering:

```
SELECT 
    Z.*, 
    Seq = Z.[Days], -- ordering column
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Z.[Days]) -- numbering
FROM dbo.z_test_duration AS Z
WHERE Z.[Status] = 'on';
```

| Days | Status | Seq | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | on | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | on | 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| 2022-01-03 | on | 2022-01-03 | 3 |
| 2022-01-05 | on | 2022-01-05 | 4 |
| 2022-01-07 | on | 2022-01-07 | 5 |
| 2022-01-08 | on | 2022-01-08 | 6 |

Notice the `Seq` values increase at the same rate as `rn` until there is a gap. We can see this more clearly by subtracting `rn` from the `Seq` value.

The only slight complication here is `Seq` is a `date`, so we need to convert that to a number before subtracting. I have used the `DATEDIFF` function here, but any consistent method of turning a date into a number would do.

```
SELECT 
    Z.*, 
    Seq = Z.[Days],
    diff = 
        DATEDIFF(DAY, '2022-01-01', Z.[Days]) - 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY Z.[Days]) 
FROM dbo.z_test_duration AS Z
WHERE Z.[Status] = 'on';
```

| Days | Status | Seq | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | on | 2022-01-01 | -1 |
| 2022-01-02 | on | 2022-01-02 | -1 |
| 2022-01-03 | on | 2022-01-03 | -1 |
| 2022-01-05 | on | 2022-01-05 | 0 |
| 2022-01-07 | on | 2022-01-07 | 1 |
| 2022-01-08 | on | 2022-01-08 | 1 |

The `diff` values are the same for every contiguous element in a group.

Now we know how to group, the final query follows directly:

```
SELECT
    ON_DATE = MIN(G.Seq), 
    OFF_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, MAX(G.Seq)),
    COUNT_OF_ACTIVE_DAYS = 1 + DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(G.Seq), MAX(G.Seq))
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        Z.*, 
        Seq = Z.[Days],
        grp = 
            DATEDIFF(DAY, '2022-01-01', Z.[Days]) - 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    ORDER BY Z.[Days]) 
    FROM dbo.z_test_duration AS Z
    WHERE Z.[Status] = 'on'
) AS G
GROUP BY G.grp;
```

| ON_DATE | OFF_DATE | COUNT_OF_ACTIVE_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-04 | 3 |
| 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-06 | 1 |
| 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-09 | 2 |

[*db<>fiddle* online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90950610297ecf9efb15515d201f9be9)